# Setting environment variable with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, export, command-line-interface

I need to set an environment variable from Node (currently using `v8.9.3`)

Ideally, I would like to run `export DATA_DIR=/var/lib/data` when the program starts.

**1.** Tried spawning a `child_process` to set this, but it does not *appear* to work.

Example:

```
const { spawnSync } = require( 'child_process' );
spawnSync( 'export', [ 'DATA_DIR=/var/lib/data' ] );
```

But this results with an `ENOENT`:

```
Error: spawnSync export ENOENT...
code: 'ENOENT',
errno: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'spawnSync export',
path: 'export',
spawnargs: [ 'DATA_DIR=/var/lib/data' ]
```

**2.** Tried setting `process.env.DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/data'` but this *appears* to be local to the node process and is not recognized by others.

**3.** Tried npm modules: `dotenv`, `envs`, `environmental`, and `tiny-envs` and these are primarily for loading envrionment variables.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set an environment variable for processes that are not descendants of the current process. And under Linux, there is no such thing as system environment variable.

`export` is not a standalone command but a shell builtin that sets the environment variable for the current shell process and its children forked after it is set. Like you open two tabs of terminal and `export` a value from this tab and use the value from other tab.

You can save the key, value to file with your format then another process can read the file to get a value of the key.

Comment: So for example, if I set the `DATA_DIR` for GeoServer, then start GeoServer from the same process, it _should_ recognize the data directory variable I just set?

Comment: @iSkore no, it not working. If you "start"  GeoServer then os is going to create a new process id and a new session for GeoServer process. I suggest use `PM2` as a process manager, PM2 api allow pass environment variables to context of new process http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-api/
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Comment: Yes, I use PM2 to start GeoServer - I was trying to keep the question a little more generic to node running on a linux environment. But, I suppose this will lean more towards GeoServer's "on start" operation and linux. So if I spin up the pid with PM2, set the ENV in my PM2 start command, GeoServer should interpret that as a typical environment variable? Not too familiar with running thing other than node apps with PM2.

Comment: @iSkore Pm2 is ok for my example https://gist.github.com/hoangsetup/3b2101ec0befef0f5b38b25c4b69b1d6

`server.js` is going to start child process `app.js` thus app.js can use env `process.env.DATA_DIR` export form the server.js (`process.env.DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/data';`)