# How can I set environment variables programmatically from nodejs?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I need to set some environment variables from within a script.

Those variables must:

1. be visible to other processes in the same shell (*not* just child processes created by this node process)
2. outlive the node process that set the variables

It is not good enough to manipulate `process.env`. I've seen a couple of SO questions that sound identical to mine, but both of them accepted answers to the effect of "assign values to `process.env[your_var]`", which fails both of my criteria.

I was using a little sugar on top of `execa`, to do (basically) this:

```js
await execa( `export MY_VAR=osmethne` )
```

But that blows up:

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 2 (ENOENT): export MY_VAR=osmethne
spawn export ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

This all happens in Dockerized linux. So, I don't need to support Windows or OS/2 Warp or any other nonsense.

Comment: I personally would need more to go on... like a miminal test case "outlive the node process that set the variables" is to cryptic for my taste. What is the use case? But ... maybe there are some NodeJs gurus out there who click with this description. Upvoting....

Comment: It looks like this may be a duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47841094/setting-environment-variable-with-nodejs). 
According to that it's not possible to do exactly what you want. Perhaps if you describe the overall problem you are trying to solve we can offer alternative solutions.

Comment: If this *was* possible it'd be a potential security risk as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`require('dotenv').config()`

in your code